# How to debug a C# paging program with repeater

Tags: c#, pagination, repeater, paging, asprepeater

I am not able to get the desired result from a post that I am following to implement on my website. I want to do paging using the repeater control.

I am referring to [this method (post)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-using-repeater-control-in-asp-net-with-and-without-stored-procedure/) for implementing the (post of [c sharp corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-using-repeater-control-in-asp-net-with-and-without-stored-procedure/))

Description of problem:

1. I don't want to implement the stored procedure feature hence I have only followed this post till step number # 3.
2. I have set the page size as 1 and I have 4 records in the database.
3. The paging repeater (repeater1 as per the code) has correctly shown 4 pages
4. Problem is that when the last page is clicked it shows no result. To explain the exact problem, I have made the incorrect code live on [this link](https://earnfreerecharge.com/post).
5. A list of all 4 posts can be viewed on [this link](https://earnfreerecharge.com/). (scroll till the bottom of the page)

What might be the main issue which is causing this issue?

**Steps taken by me:**
 1. I have tried setting the pdsData.CurrentPageIndex = 0;   to 1 at row # 41 (step 3) - problem not solved
 2. I tried setting

```
ViewState["PageNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

as

```
ViewState["PageNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)+1;
```

problem is still the same (row number 61 or step 3)

I am open to alternatives to achieving an efficient paging using repeater control. I am using asp.net version 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem in the code is with **for loop**:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= pdsData.PageCount; i++)  
alPages.Add((i).ToString());
```

This loop has been initialized as i=1 while index usually starts with ZERO. I have changed this initialization as i=0. This made my for loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pdsData.PageCount; i++)  
alPages.Add((i).ToString());
```

This fixed the issue of the extra page which is blank.

**Note:** This solution will initiate the pager (page numbers in the bottom) start from 0, 1, 2, etc instead of 1, 2, 3, and so on.

I fixed this by adding one (+1) to the bound filed in the .aspx page. see the example below:

```
<%#Int32.Parse( Container.DataItem.ToString())+1%>
```

These edits have made the **paging using repeater bug-free** and smooth.